# Can I use AdSense in a local web page?

Tags: web-services, web-applications, adsense

I have written a desktop application that uses a web page as the GUI, so it's a local site so to say. Then, is it possible to insert AdSense into this page and earn some cash with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe AdSense needs to be able to crawl through the site in order to categorise it to determine which ads to show: if it's locally hosted, this wouldn't be possible.

Comment: Nick is right. http://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!topic/adsense/SK5cvXp-IlU

Comment: I see. Another question comes to my mind though. If there was no crawling problem, how would the ads know that the earnings should come to my account, if the page is locally hosted, hence not on my remote server?

Comment: The links are tied to your publisher account: when it's clicked, Google records a number of statistics.

Comment: That is good news to me since there might be a chance to do some legal hack or use a different ad system in order to get some funding. I thought it wouldn't be possible if the ads weren't in my own site. Thanks for the quick answer!